# Stopping NameNode in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

`jps` shows that the NameNode Java process is running.

But when I try to stop it using

```
stop-all.sh
```

or

```
stop-dfs.sh
```

it shows the message 'No NameNode to stop'.

Same thing happens with `JobTracker` as well.

I am unable to figure where the problem could be.

Comment: To deploy the clusters, I have followed the pseudo-distribution setup, as explain at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html

Comment: can you show me what you got when you done `start-all.sh` ?

Comment: Are hadoop processes run by a different user? Or may be root user?
Have you checked namenode logs?

Comment: The problem was I tried to stop it as a different user. Got it solved now.